Issue with body mesh moving to cursor
I scaled the models down with the scale button thing.
(im new to blender)
I have deleted the armature of 1 to see if that fixed it. it hasnt.
there are a string and a ball attached. ive tried repositioning them, it doesnt work.

Every time i copy and paste the body meshes, they go to where the cursor is.
Even after moving the cursor, they still go to the same spot.
I cant save the project until this is fixed.

file:///C:/Users/dr120/OneDrive/Desktop/Desktop%20Files/Screenshots/Capture.JPG
screenshot
not sure if its visible..

this is a link to your local computer...unfortunately we cannot access that.

Here is a different link.. sorry
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z0BwNC7EKzmoRYWHTL8NQY8YJzvOGbxv/view?usp=sharing

Hello, Karasu, welcome to BSE. You have not stated your problem clearly. Please edit this post  to say, as simply as possible: what you want, what you've got , and what the difference is. Make it about one problem. (You can ask other questions about other problems)..
